# How can I set a folder undeletable but have R/W permissions to it's content

Tags: permissions, directory

I have a directory which I'd like to mark as not deleteable, but have all the usual permissions of read/write/delete on all subdirectories and files. How can I achieve this?

I tried setting the `undeletable` flag via `chattr` but it only works on files and apparently doesn't even prevent deleting, but allows restoring the file. Setting the `immutable` flag prevents deleting the dir but also prevents changing anything in it.